# How to enumerate Home Videos in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, video

I understand how to enumerate images and video in the photo library using `PHPhotoLibrary`, but videos added through iTunes as "home videos", and visible only through the new TV app under the Home Video section, don't appear in that enumeration.

Is there another way of querying for them?

Comment: Does the TV app still exists? I try to find the TV app on my 6s running iOS 12. I can only find the movie app. What iOS are you running?

Comment: I have it on iOS 11, 12 isn't out yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it looks like the only other thing you can try to use are the **Media Player** API's.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediaquery

> A query that specifies a set of media items from the device's media
>   library by way of a filter and a grouping type.

That might work, since I assume that your synced movies are part of the media library and not part of the photo library.

First you need to add the `NSAppleMusicUsageDescription` to your `Info.plist`. Then we can use `MPMediaQuery` and filter out the home video items.

```
let predicate: MPMediaPropertyPredicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: MPMediaType.homeVideo.rawValue, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType)

let query: MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.init()
query.addFilterPredicate(predicate)

let items = query.items

for item : MPMediaItem in items!
{
    // Here is your home video
}
```

See the `MPMediaTypeHomeVideo` item: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mediaplayer/mpmediatype/mpmediatypehomevideo

Now `items` should contain all your home videos.

EDIT: I tested it, and it works for me on iOS 12, however `title` seems to be empty. You can access the video file itself using the `assetURL` property.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an updated method.

```swift
import MediaPlayer

    func video() {
        
        MPMediaLibrary.requestAuthorization() { status in
            
            if status == .authorized {
                let predicate: MPMediaPropertyPredicate = MPMediaPropertyPredicate(value: MPMediaType.homeVideo.rawValue, forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType)
                
                let query: MPMediaQuery = MPMediaQuery.init()
                query.addFilterPredicate(predicate)
                
                if let items = query.items {
                    
                    for item in items {
                        // Here is your home video
                        print(item.title ?? "title?")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

you'll need to add this key to your info.plist

`Privacy - Media Library Usage Description`