# How to create video list in ios?(swiftui)

Tags: swift, objective-c, video, swiftui, media-player

I want to make a list in my app that shows the videos stored in the device's internal memory

Should I use **MediaPlayer**?

Or is there another way?

Comment: I think this link will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689305/how-to-enumerate-home-videos-in-ios

Comment: So thanks but i want a better answer if you know please help me